# joomla 2.5 pagination is not showing next articles

Tags: pagination, joomla2.5

i'm using joomla 2.5 with rockettheme template and the pagination is not working on the client side. when I press on page 2 I see the same articles from page 1. next/prev is not working.
what i tried is to change the template to joomla template and it didn't work. i also deleted the file .htaccess.
i'm use seowebhosting.net for the host.

what could be the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: yes. www.roulettesystems.co/

Comment: There is something wrong with your pagination module as a button contains for example http://www.roulettesystems.co/?limitstart=0 This only ads a parameter but doesn't do anything. U can try to disable out of date plugins. And make sure u are using the latest version of the fracture theme.

Comment: i tried to search for a date plugin and i didn't see it. also i don't think its template issue because i changed it to the default theme and it still didn't work